# How does the sea change over time?

Tags: sunless-sea

Various game messages in *Sunless Sea* allude to the fact that the sea might change as days pass. How does it change, exactly?

[image]

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the message, as Sporks is trying to hint at it in his answer. What the message in the game actually says is that your time at sea will change **you**. Now, I'm not sure what that means, but I'm quite certain it doesn't mean the sea will change!

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't.

The only thing that changes is "Something Awaits You" which can cause random effects at various ports. Also, some ports have stories which progress as time passes.

But it's not like something "changes" in the sense you mean. Islands don't move. New stories don't appear out of nowhere. It's just flavour text.

There are a couple of things which trigger after you've spent a year at Zee, but they're not big events, mostly just related to a couple of officers, and nothing that will affect the game in any significant way.

Comment: -1; this is wrong. There are choices whose availability is explicitly dependent upon the value of the "Another Day" variable circled in the asker's screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

There are some options on some islands that only become visible once your *"Another Day: Time, the Healer"* property is large enough. For instance (minor spoiler):

> [image: Screenshot showing such an option.]

Answer (score -2):

When you visit port with a something awaits you at port token (that you get by basically driving around) you get options you would not have otherwise

Comment: I wasn't talking about the new port event thing. I've updated my question to clarify what I meant.